# "by as much as 8 percent" means "by 8 percent" or "by up to 8 percent"?

Tags: meaning

The authors of the study, one of the most closely watched overviews of the global high-end retail market, predicted that such expansion would drive up growth across the global luxury market **by as much as 8 percent**.

My question: what does "**by as much as 8 percent**" mean? Does it mean "**by 8 percent**" or "**by up to 8 percent**"?

Thanks,
Jeffrey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As much as:

> You use as much as before an amount to suggest that it is surprisingly large.[emphasis]
>
> - *The organisers hope to raise as much as £6m for charity.*

( Collins Dictionary)

The author is saying that they expect a growth  around, up to, but probably no more than 8%.

Comment: so, the growth may be 2%, 4%, or 8%, but no more than 8%?

Comment: It is a forecast, they expect a growth around 8%.

Comment: I would interpret it as they _hope for_ growth of 8%, but it certainly could be less.  (Unless this is a sales pitch in which case they probably expect less than 8% but figure the mark, er, customer would believe 8%.)

Comment: Well, here's another interpretation:  8% is the organisers' forecast, but the person writing the sentence thinks that is very ambitious. "What, 8%! They'll be lucky!"